# Can I use my early 2009 iMac as an external screen?

Tags: imac, target-display

I have an early 2009 iMac (24" version). It has a mini display port in the back. Is it possible to use it as an external screen? If so, how do I do it? And can I attach all kinds of devices, e.g. a Raspberry Pi (with an appropriate adapter cable)?

Comment: Were you able to confirm that an early 2009 24" iMac does *not* support TDM?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [specifications for the 24" Early 2009 iMacs according to eveymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-24-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html) and the [Apple Manual for the Early 2009 series of iMacs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-24-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html) does not mention target display mode as a feature.  That unfortunately means that the Early 2009 generation of iMacs did not offer a target display mode so you will not be able to use that displayport output as an input source.

Comment: [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) for using iMacs in Target Display Mode seems to confirm it, unfortunately: the earliest listed model is the Late 2009 one.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the [user manual for your particular model](http://support.apple.com/manuals/) for Command-F2 as a shortcut to enter target display mode.

If yours has a target display mode, you are good to go. If not, then no.

I don't think that any 24-inch iMac model supports this. Initially the 27-inch models had this feature and later it trickled down to the 21-inch models.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find this information on Everymac.com or in the manual. Apple's own webpage on Target Display Mode says:

24-inch and 27-inch iMac models introduced in 2009 and 2010
To use any of these iMac models as an external display:

- The iMac used as a display must have macOS High Sierra or earlier installed.
- The other Mac that you're connecting it to must have been introduced in 2019 or earlier and have macOS Catalina or earlier installed.
- The cable connecting the two Mac computers must be a Mini DisplayPort  cable.

SHORT ANSWER: The 24 inch iMac from 2009 WILL WORK as an external screen.