# How can I use an old mac as an external display using software?

Tags: imac, screen, sharing

I want to use a "space" or "application" with another computer on the network. Just the UI not keyboard and mouse.

The other goal is to add a pseudo screen, without getting an extra monitor. Can't use os x native screen sharing as that will always have the same content as current action space.

Any ideas..?

old mac  = imac 2009, so cannot use as a targetted display. can use hardware to make it happen.

Similar to [Can I use my early 2009 iMac as an external screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53727/can-i-use-my-early-2009-imac-as-an-external-screen)

also similar to http://synergy-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems **ScreenRecycler** does what you need. There's a [trial version](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) available, so you can try it.

[image: screenshot]