# How to use an old iMac as an external display for a MacBook via wifi?

Tags: imac, display, airplay, screen-sharing

There have been several questions how to connect a (new) MacBook to an (old) iMac so the latter will work as a second, bigger display for the former, but all were assuming a hardware connection, i.e. a DVI, Displayport or Thunderbolt cable. Apple even has a [support page for Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), which is only available in a limited number of recent, but not too recent iMacs. I’m looking for a **software solution**, because though (Mini) Display Port is available on both my devices, they only support video *output*:

[image: The connectors of the 2006 iMacs]
[image: The connectors of the 2010 MacBook Air]

I’m trying to connect a [2010 MBA](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP617) running OS X 10.10.5 with a [2006 iMac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201758) running 10.6.8, the latest OS X available for that model. Both are connected to the same private wifi network.

[Avatron Air Display](http://avatron.com/support/faq-air-display/) seems like it could work, but versions 2 and 3 don’t support OS X 10.6 any more and if I try to connect v3 with v1.6 it fails. [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org) may be an alternative, but before wasting 10 bucks I’d like to know if anyone had luck with that piece of software in a setup like mine.

- Are there other alternatives that I didn’t find, maybe even free ones?
- Could I somehow get at least AirPlay video support? The iMac runs [Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/Airplay) (previously known as XBMC) which allegedly offers *some* AirPlay capability.
- If surprisingly there was a hardware solution I’ve overlooked (e.g. using USB or, *cough*, Firewire), that would be fantastic of course.

I’m not quite sure whether [How can I use an old mac as an external display using software?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162561/how-can-i-use-an-old-mac-as-an-external-display-using-software) was asking the same thing.

Comment: It seems AirPlay mirroring is not supported on the [2010 MBA](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343), so that option is off for me, but maybe not others in a similar situation, so I’m leaving it in the question.

Comment: [Avatron Air Display Host 1.7](http://downloads.avatron.com/AirDisplayInstaller-17.zip) works, but is a bit slow, i.e. there are some compression artifacts visible for about a second when there are bigger screen updates.

Answer (score 1):

I've [answered the question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162561/how-can-i-use-an-old-mac-as-an-external-display-using-software/207273#207273) you've mentioned. Perhaps it helps you too:

> It seems **ScreenRecycler** does what you need. There's a [trial version](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) available, so you can try it.

Comment: Screen Recycler starts being 64bit only after version 1.3.8, though.